# Как копию сайта перенести на новый домен и на новую админку?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, cms, drupal

Подскажите пожалуйста, как копию сайта Drupal перенести на новый домен и новую админку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так:

1. Оформляешь новый хост
2. Заходишь на старый, в FTP, копируешь все файлы
3. Заходишь в БД, там в настройках есть ф-ция копирования, скачиваешь базу...
4. Делаешь тоже самое, ток наоборот на новом хостинге
5. Если нужно перенести домен, нужно в настройках сменить NS адреса, новые ты найдешь у нового хостера в инструкции...

Или обратись в службу поддержки нового хостинга, многие переносят бесплатно...

Comment: https://rigweb.ru/support/cms/kak-vypolnyaetsya-perenos-sayta-drupal-na-drugoy-khosting/

Comment: Немного добавлю: копирование с сервера на сервер лучше провести не посредством ftp, а командой scp (утилита из набора ssh). Синтаксис: scp -r root@server1.my:/home/dir/ root@server2.my:/home/dir/

Comment: А как сменить админку в Drupal?

Comment: Админку Drupal можно изменить в БД...